# Need a "yarn/npm link" workflow for dev and publishing for "multiple copies of react" module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am building and publishing a module to npm. The module is dependent on `React`. I am currently using `yarn` and `yarn link`.

I have built this module in a parent project and now am trying to extract it to a standalone module. I want to continue developing the module locally as part of the parent project.

The `package.json` in the module looks like:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-reconciler": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "regl": "^1.3.0",
}
```

I include this module in a parent projection by running `yarn link` in the module directory and then `yarn link module-name` in the parent directory. When included in the parent project an error is then thrown

> Element ref was specified as a string (canvas) but no owner was set.
>   You may have multiple copies of React loaded. (details:
>   https://reactjs.org/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).

I have previously tried this workflow using `npm` instead of `yarn` and had the same issues.

I'm hoping this is a solved problem with a boilerplate. I've looked at other projects and haven't seen a common solution. I"m looking for a high-level best practices answer. I'm open to configurations using `webpack` `rollup` or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Webpack you can use `resolve.alias` a long with npm/yarn link in order to have all dependencies use a single instance of React from your host app.

In your development Webpack config add the following:

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
   },
},
```

Comment: What if you're using Rollup.js? What's a good dev workflow to combine your UI library which is bundled with Rollup, and your app project which is importing that local UI library and using webpack + webpack-dev-server?

Answer (score 1):

The option I'm currently using on my projects consist of skipping `npm`/`yarn` linking at all, and add a NPM script to [symlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_symlinksync_target_path_type) any local package into `node_modules` folder like:

- create an empty `node_modules` folder
- run local dependencies linking script
- install NPM dependencies from root project

If module and the hosting project declares compatible `React` dependencies you should end up with **your local module symlinked** and **just one `React` instance installed**.

You might also want to automate local dependencies linking with tools like [this](https://github.com/timoxley/linklocal).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. This appears to require the parent/host project to have a local file path in its `package.json` how is this handled when deploying to environments that don't have the local module?

Comment: Once published, the aformentioned packages will be consumed as normal NPM dependencies. As long as they declare compatible dependencies against React, NPM should be able to make them rely on the same React instance.

Comment: For clarification, I was talking about the host project, 'The app', not the module that gets published to NPM. 'The App' is the codebase that would traditionally do `npm link module_name`.  This sounds like when deploying 'The App' I would have to edit package.json to change the local path to that of an NPM package name, and do the reverse when in Development.

Comment: What I suggested is to symlink the local module I into node_modules folder when in dev, and let package.json declare a normal NPM registry dependency on that module.

Answer (score 0):

The externals in webpack config will be useful.

```js
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: ['react', 'react-dom'],
}
```

Normally the react component library does not need to be installed react.